# Transmit FM via android

Tags: java, android, fm-radio

I want to buy FM transmitter such as [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Portable-Car-FM-Radio-Transmitter-For-iPhone-4-5-Samsung-Galaxy-S-2-3-II-III-/261300615584). Is it possible to communicate with the transmitter from Android device using Android API? change freq. etc.

If not - Is there any FM hardware that can communicate with android API? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Android device can communicate with the FM transmitter via the USB. See [USB Host Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html).

Another alternative is to connect the FM transmitter to a micro-controller, or a ready kit like Arduino, which is also connected to a Wi-Fi or Bluetooth module, then communication would be occurred through that channel.